# Join two 1D Arrays (A[] and B[]) into one 2D array (C[,])

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two 1D arrays :

```
double A = new double[7] {4, 2, 54, 16, 9, 55, 27}
```

and

```
double B = new double[7] {8, 88, 21, 12, 8, 30, 11}
```

how can i join those array become one 2D array C[2,6], that contain both 1D array above?

probably like this :

```
double C = new double[2,7] {{4, 2, 54, 16, 9, 55, 27} , {8, 88, 21, 12, 8, 30, 11}};
```

I tried this code but, only array A printed.

```
public static double[,] _matrix_byRow(double[] Mat1, double[] Mat2)
    {
        int i, j, y;
        double[,] newMat = new double[2, 7];

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                newMat[i, j] = Mat1[j];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 7; y++)
            {
                newMat[i, y] = Mat2[y];
            }
        }
        return newMat;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public static double[,] _matrix_byRow(double[] Mat1, double[] Mat2)
{
    double[,] newMat = new double[2, 7];

    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        newMat[0, j] = Mat1[j];
        newMat[1, j] = Mat2[j];
    }

    return newMat;
}
```

Comment: @Yaltha - No trouble. Can you mark this as the answer then?